# Google Maps Engine custom search KML

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-maps-engine

I have a KML file with 74 points and some info on the description field. These points represent some stores around my city. Im working on Google Maps engine and I uploaded the file, it was processed and it displays on the base map perfectly. The problem comes when I try to find an specific store using the search box in the Maps engine interface. It does not show any of the stores uploaded in the KML file. Same thing when I try to see it on the Maps engine app for android, the points are displayed on the map, i can see the description info on each point, but when I want to find one in particular using the serch box, it does not show any of the points as a result.

This is the KML code of one of the points (store)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>KmlFile</name>
    <Style id="icon-503-009D57">
        <IconStyle>
            <color>ff579d00</color>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Disensa Sixto Robayo</name>
        <description>Latitud: -2.276092
Longitud: -79.894329
Direccion: Av. Cacique Tomalá Mz 63 Solar 12
Telefono: 042486407
Contacto: Sixto Robayo Niza
Ciudad: Guayaquil</description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-503-009D57</styleUrl>
        <ExtendedData>
            <Data name="string">
                <displayName>Ciudad</displayName>
                <value>Guayaquil</value>
            </Data>
        </ExtendedData>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-79.894329,-2.276092,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the product. Is this Maps Engine Lite or Platform? Hint: If it was free it's probably Lite